# Sort numbers in jQuery Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sorting, datatables

I have a table have 6 columns , I used datatable:

```
 $('#datatable2').dataTable({
                "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "Search " },
                "oSearch": { "sSearch": "<% = requestId %>" }
               });
```

when I use this table appear very nice but it didn't sort numbers 
when I add this

```
 $('#datatable2').dataTable({
                     "aoColumns": [
                               { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
                               null,
                               null,
                               null, null, null],

                "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "search: " },
                "oSearch": { "sSearch": "<% = requestId %>" }
               });
```

it sort number correctly but it appears all the rows not 10 by 10 or 50 by 50 as  this pic

please help!

[image]

when I use this code

```
paging:true,
"aoColumns": [{ "sType": "numeric" }, null, null,null , null, null],
```

it appear gridview as 
[image]

it sort as I need but why it get number 129 in the second row ?

Note that:-
My integer numbers is hyperlink

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable pagination, so `datatables` know how to deal with more then page length number of rows. Parameter `paging` = `true` (https://datatables.net/reference/option/paging).

```
$('#datatable2').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null],
    "paging": true,
    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "search: " },
    "oSearch": { "sSearch": "<% = requestId %>" }
});
```

You can also change pagination type https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

Please not that `paging` and `pagingType` parameters were introduced (or rather renamed) in **datatables 1.10**.

For *legacy* names of those parameters check https://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options

**Update**: In order to set the default sorting for the table you have to specify `order` parameter https://datatables.net/reference/option/order.

Your table initialization will look like this:

```
$('#datatable2').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sType": "numeric-comma" },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        null],
    "paging": true,
    "oLanguage": { "sSearch": "search: " },
    "oSearch": { "sSearch": "<% = requestId %>" },
    "order": [[ 0, 'asc' ]]
});
```

I'm still not sure that I fully understand your question, sorry.

Comment: thanks for your precious time, but there is a strange behavior which I can't understand ,when I use `"sType": "numeric-comma"` it sort correctly but no paging as the First image in the question , and when I use `"sType": "numeric"` it view the paging very well but appear the second row with wrong sorting as second image in the question .

Comment: Can it be something related to RTL support? Try left-to-right setup.

Comment: Sorry can't understand , but I forget to say that the First column is numbers with hyperlink